# Representing Green function as a coherent state path integral

Tags: condensed-matter, field-theory, greens-functions, propagator, coherent-states

I am working through the problem "self-consistent T-matrix approximation" in Altland and Simons (second edition) pg 234. One of the steps involves representing the Green function as a coherent state path integral and performing the Gaussian integral over the Grassman field, and the solution given in the book is quite brief. I would like more details so I can follow the derivation.

I've taken the below from [this physics overflow link](https://www.physicsoverflow.org/25400/green-function-for-single-impurity?state=edit-25400), which summarizes well the statement of the problem (but is ultimately asking about different aspects of the problem).

> The Hamiltonian of the problem is $\hat H = \hat H_0 + \hat H_{\text{imp}} \; $, where
> $$\hat H_0 = \sum_{\mathbf{k}} \epsilon_{\mathbf{k}} c_{\mathbf{k}}^\dagger c_{\mathbf{k}},$$
> $$\hat H_{imp} = v_0 a^d \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N_{imp}} c^{\dagger}(\mathbf{R_i})c(\mathbf{R_i}),$$
> and $N_{\text{imp}} \; $ is the number of impurities. We want to compute the single-particle Green function $G_n = \langle \langle c^{\dagger}_n (\mathbf{r}) c_n(\mathbf{r'}) \rangle \rangle_{imp} \; $, where $n$ is the Matsubara frequency index and $\langle \cdots \rangle_{imp} \equiv \frac{1}{L^d} \int \prod_i d^d\mathbf{R_i}$ is the configurational average over all impurity coordinates.

In the first line of the solution given on page 236:

> Representing the Green function as a coherent state path integral and performing the Gaussian integral over the Grassman field, we obtain the formal result $\hat{G}_n = (i \omega_n - \hat{H}_0 - \hat{H}_{\text{imp}} \; )^{-1}$.

I would like some details about how to do this. For example, are $c(r), c_k$ the same operators except one is in real space and the other in momentum space, or do they represent different operators entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure is this is all you need, but the answer to your question is yes, the operators are the same, just expressed in real vs k-space:
$$
c({\bf{r}})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}\sum_k c_k e^{-i \bf{k r}},\quad c({\bf k})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int c(r) e^{i \bf{k r}}d{\mathbf r}
$$
(the sign convention was picked up from (2.24))

As of the "formal correct result", you can demonstrate in general case, that if the Green's function is defined as
$$
G_{n,\alpha\beta}=\langle \bar{c}_{n\alpha} c_{n\beta} \rangle,
$$
(here the averaging is defined through the path integral and Grassman variables),
and your Hamiltonian is
$$
{\bf{H}}=\sum_{\alpha\beta}H_{\alpha\beta}c_\alpha^{\dagger} c_\beta, 
$$
then it is possible to show (see the equation right after Eq. 4.22) that the Green function
$$
G_{n,\alpha\beta} \, \equiv \frac{1}{Z} \int Dc D\bar c\, \bar{c}_{n\alpha} \;  c_{n\beta} \; e^{\sum_{\, n\alpha\beta} \; \;  {\bar{c}_{\, n\alpha} \; (i\omega_n \; \delta_{\alpha\beta} } \; \; -H_{\alpha\beta} \; ) \, c_{\beta n}}, 
$$
if treated as a matrix with indices $\alpha$ and $\beta$, can be expressed as
$$
G_{n,\alpha\beta}=G_n=(i\omega_n-H)^{-1},
$$
which is essentially how the "technical solution" is obtained.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the part "see the equation right after Eq. 4.22"? I don't quite see how that equation $\int d \eta f(\eta) = \int d \eta f(\eta  + \nu)$ is relevant here. Thanks!

Comment: No, it is the equation right before the chapter 4.2. Namely, $\langle \phi_{j_1}\phi_{j_2}...\phi_{j_n}\bar{\phi}_{j_n}...\bar{\phi}_{j_2}\phi_{j_1}\rangle=\sum_P(\text{sgn}P)A^{-1}_{j_1i_{P1}}...A^{-1}_{j_ni_{Pn}}$

Comment: Thanks! That is super helpful. In your second-to-last equation $G_{n, \, \alpha \beta} \; \equiv \int \ldots$, should the RHS should be divided by $\int Dc D\bar{c} \; e^{\sum_{\, n\alpha\beta} \; \;  {\bar{c}_{\, n\alpha} \; (i\omega_n \; \delta_{\alpha\beta} } \; \; -H_{\alpha\beta} \; ) \, c_{\beta n}} \quad$?

Comment: Yes, you are right, good catch